# Javascript calendar skips days during leapyear?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a calendar in javascript and jquery (adapted from ["Simple Calendar with Javascript"](http://en.wikicode.org/index.php/Simple_calendar_with_JavaScript)) that allows me to move back and forward months at a time.

It accounts for leap years by adding in an extra day every 4 years in February, but it seems that an error is being caused because of this.

When you move back in time, or forward, it changes the date and runs the `calendar()` function according to the new date. Normally, it has 5 rows with 7 columns, each column containing a day. If there isn't enough room with the 5 rows, such as there being 31 days with the 1st being on a Saturday, then it will add an extra 6th row to accommodate.

During a leap year, however, the function doesn't seem to add the extra rows in if the same scenario above happens.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/DrMWM/

This gist of `calendar()`:

```
function calendar(d){

                $("#calendar").remove();
                $("body").append("<table border='1' id='calendar'></table>");

                // Date vars
                var today = new Date(d);
                var month = today.getMonth();
                var day = today.getDay();
                var dayN = today.getDate();
                var week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
                var monthdays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
                var days = monthdays[month];
                var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

                // Determine if leap year, if not, set to current year
                if (month > 0) {
                    year = today.getYear();
                    if (year % 4 == 0){
                        days = 29;
                    }
                } else {
                    year = today.getYear();
                }

                // Parse vars
                var jumped = 0;
                var inserted = 1;
                var start = day - dayN%7 + 1;
                if (start < 0) start += 7;
                var weeks = parseInt((start + days)/7);
                if ((start + days)%7 != 0){
                    weeks++;
                }

                $("#calendar").append("<tr><td class='month' colspan='7'>" + monthNames[month] + " - " + today.getFullYear() + "</td></tr>");

                $("#calendar").append("<tr class='day'></tr>");
                for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
                    $(".day").append("<td>" + week[i][0] + "</td>");
                }

                function datDate(m, n, y){
                    date = new Date(" " + monthNames[m] + " " + n + " " + y);
                    return date;
                }

                for (var i=weeks; i>0; i--) {
                    if (i === i){
                        $("#calendar").append("<tr class=" + i + "></tr>");
                        for (var j=0; j<7; j++) {
                            console.log(inserted);
                            if (jumped<start || inserted>days) {
                                $("." + i).append("<td> </td>");
                                jumped++;
                            }
                            else {
                                m = month;
                                n = inserted;
                                y = today.getFullYear();
                                date = datDate(m, n, y);
                                if (inserted == dayN) {
                                    $("." + i).append("<td><a class='calendar_date current_date' data-date='" + date + "'>[" + n + "]</a></td>");
                                } else {
                                    $("." + i).append("<td><a class='calendar_date' data-date='" + date + "'>" + n + "</a></td>");
                                }
                                inserted++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
```

Comment: Why not just iterate through the days in the month you're trying to render, and let the built in Date library do all the heavy lifting?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? This sounds like a much cleaner way...

Comment: @Charlie you can simply increment the day-of-month; the library "fixes" the date if you try to set it to January 32 in other words, and the date comes out February 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10040679/176741 for some date range and then render them back to text however you'd like with http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @Dolph [Be wary of w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)  The [MDN documentation site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is generally more reliable, and if you do find a problem there you can fix it yourself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            // Determine if leap year, if not, set to current year
            if (month == 1) {
                year = today.getYear();
                if (year % 4 == 0){
                    days = 29;
                }
            } else {
                year = today.getYear();
            }
```

Comment: This is not accurate - a leap year has more rules than just dividing by 4 and checking the remainder: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Leap-Years