# Getting list of dates between two dates not returning correctly JS

Tags: javascript, date

I have a start date and an end date, and I want to generate a list of dates between (and including) these two dates. But I don't get why it isn't working...

I pass in a couple of JS date objects, I've shown what they log to the console below

```
function dateList(dateStart, dateEnd) {
  console.log(dateStart);
  console.log(dateEnd);
  var dates = [];
  for ( i = dateStart; i <= dateEnd; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1) ){
    dates.push(i);
  }
  return dates
}



Mon May 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
Fri May 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

The array that is returned is

```
Array[5] 
0: Sat May 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
1: Sat May 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
2: Sat May 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
3: Sat May 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
4: Sat May 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

...Why???......

Comment: You change `i` in every iteration, and you add a reference to `i` to the array each time. So all elements in the array will be the same.

Comment: Here is something that should help you, to add a context to what Arg0n said  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345045/javascript-loop-between-date-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `new Date(i)`, instead of just `i`:

```js
function dateList(dateStart, dateEnd) {
  var dates = [];
  for (i = dateStart; i <= dateEnd; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)){
    dates.push(new Date(i));
  }
  return dates;
}

console.log(dateList(new Date('2017-05-08'), new Date('2017-05-12')));
```

Comment: Might be better to use `var i = new Date(dateStart)`. *startDate* is passed to the function so best not to modify it in the loop. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code `i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)` doesn't create a new date - it just updates the same Date object over and over. Then you push that object onto the array, which pushes a reference to that object - not a copy of the object.

A solution would be to create a `new Date()` inside the loop and setting the value of it, and then pushing this new date onto your array.

Answer (score 0):

Because the same object is modified all elements referencing the same object