# Javascript/Jquery : How Loop value date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

In normal Loop, we can loop number :

```
for(var i=1; i <= 4; i++){
 console.log(i);//result : 1,2,3,4
}
```

And this case, i want to do loop with value date, so i can get date range.

```
for(var i="11-04-2018"; i <= "14-04-2018"; i++){
  console.log(i);
  //hope can like this result : 11-04-2018,12-04-2018,13-04-2018,14-04-2018
}
```

But i know that's code, will be error :( 
Hope someone can understand what i mean :)

Thanks..

Comment: Hope this will help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345045/javascript-loop-between-date-ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345045/javascript-loop-between-date-ranges)

Comment: @Ash thanks verry much, that's helpme :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript loop between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345045/javascript-loop-between-date-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I know how to loop value date: 
Just do like this, and work:

```
var now = new Date(2018, 5, 12);
var daysOfYear = [];
for (var d = new Date(2018, 5, 10); d <= now; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    daysOfYear.push(new Date(d));
}
console.log(daysOfYear)
```

source: [Javascript loop between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345045/javascript-loop-between-date-ranges)