# Confusing JS loop behavior with dates

Tags: javascript, loops, date

The following code, which I tweaked from [this prior SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655646/4386239), attempts to loop over the range from 2/5/13 to 2/10/13, including both endpoints.

```
var start = new Date("02/05/2013");
var end = new Date("02/10/2013");

var output = [];
var loop = new Date(start);
alert(loop)
while(loop < end){           
    output.push(loop);
    var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
    loop = new Date(newDate);
}
var strings = JSON.stringify(output);

var pgraf = document.createElement('p');
var ptext = document.createTextNode(strings)
pgraf.appendChild(ptext)
document.body.appendChild(pgraf);
```

For some reason that I don't understand, however, while the alert before the loop alerts 2/5/13 as one would expect, the first item in the actual output array is 2/6/13.  So the string ultimately appended to the dom is

["2013-02-06T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-07T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-08T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-09T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-10T07:00:00.000Z"]

So that's mystery #1.

Mystery #2: I tried to trim this code down a little bit, by replacing everything from the creation of the output array to the end of the loop with:

```
var output = [start];
while(start < end){           
    var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    start = new Date(newDate);
    output.push(start);
```

}

But this time, the output is even weirder: it doesn't include the initial value of the start variable at all, but does include the last value twice.

["2013-02-06T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-07T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-08T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-09T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-10T07:00:00.000Z","2013-02-10T07:00:00.000Z"]

Clearly I don't understand what's happening in the loop here.  But I've been programming in non-JS languages for a few years now---I like to think I understand how loops work!  Can anyone tell me what I'm screwing up here?

Comment: Please read [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript/)

Comment: Are you aware that setDate changes the date instance in place?

Comment: I was not... whoops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `loop` variable you are modifying in the last line of your while loop is still the same `loop` you inserted into the array at the start.

If you make a `new Date(loop)` and insert that instead you won't get that side effect.

`setDate` modifies the date you call it on so the third line if your loop is unnecessary.

Lastly if you want to include both start and end, use `<=` instead of `<`

```js
var start = new Date("02/05/2013");
var end = new Date("02/10/2013");

var output = [];
var loop = new Date(start);

while(loop <= end){           
    output.push(new Date(loop));
    loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(output)
```